# Data is not fetching from API in IONIC app in android device, Chrome it works fine

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic framework. I am working on project using ionic 1, I have created side menu app.
In this am fetching play list data from database when playlists controller loads, I am using nodejs and Mongodb as backend. In chrome(IONIC Serve) it is fetching data from db but when I run into android device(ionic cordova run android) it is not loading API.
I am unable to find what went wrong, I have referred stackoverflow and many article but couldn't.
I have seen many of them facing this issue, I had tried what they are telling to do but no luck.
Please help me to find the error.

App.js

```js
var wowzer = angular.module('wowzer', ['ionic'])



wowzer.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('login', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
            controller: 'AppCtrl'
        })
        .state('app', {
            url: '/app',
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
            controller: 'AppCtrl'
        })

    .state('app.search', {
        url: '/search',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/search.html'
            }
        }
    })

    .state('app.browse', {
            url: '/browse',
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/browse.html'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('app.playlists', {
            url: '/playlists',
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/playlists.html',
                    controller: 'PlaylistsCtrl'
                }
            }
        })

    .state('app.single', {
        url: '/playlists/:playlistId',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/playlist.html'
            }
        }
    });
    // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});

wowzer.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
    });
})
```

Index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' yourhost.com ws://localhost:35729; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *;script-src 'self' localhost:35729 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline';">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
    <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
    <script>
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
          .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
          .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
      }
    </script>-->
    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->
    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/logInControllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/playListController.js"></script>
    <script src="services/logInServices.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="wowzer">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>

</html>
```

playlistController

```js
wowzer.controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function($scope, logInServices) {

    logInServices.fetchAllItem().then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.data);
        $scope.playlists = response.data;
    });

})
```

.services.js

```js
wowzer.factory('logInServices', function($http) {
 userFactory = {};
 //User.create(regData);
 userFactory.fetchAllItem = function() {

  return $http.get('http://localhost:8100/api/fetchdata');
 }
 return userFactory;
})
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```js
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="io.ionic.wowzer" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
</manifest>
```

config.xml

```js
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.ionic.wowzer" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>WOWZER</name>
    <description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://ionic.local/*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
    </platform>
    <engine name="android" spec="^6.2.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="^1.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.1.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.2" />
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1" />
</widget>
```

Plalist API

```js
module.exports = function(router) {
    router.get('/fetchdata', function(req, res) {
        var playlists = [
            { title: 'Reggae', id: 1 },
            { title: 'Chill', id: 2 },
            { title: 'Dubstep', id: 3 },
            { title: 'Indie', id: 4 },
            { title: 'Rap', id: 5 },
            { title: 'Cowbell', id: 6 }
        ];
        console.log(playlists);
        res.json(playlists);
    });
    return router;
}
```

Please help me where I did wrong.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Run with below command, get the console logs.Then you will get an issue it's easy to solve.

```
ionic run android -l -c -s
```

-l stands for livereload
-c stands for consolelogs
-s stands for serverlogs
After using the livereload, I didn't face this issue.Try with it.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is due to the fact that by default ionic does not allow http connections .... so to overcome this problem, add to the AndroidManifest.xml file located in /android/app/src/main as follows (sa marche chez moi)

````
```
<application 
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```
````

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyUmZ.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFWr2.png)